# prevent execution after any given line in sql script

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

When I need to execute part of a SQL Script I comment the lines I don't want to run with /**/. This doesn't work properly when the script being commented contains comments itself. Is there a magic command that I can put between lines to prevent what comes next to be executed?

The SQL Script:

```
SELECT ColumnA FROM TableA;
SELECT ColumnB FROM TableB;
SELECT ColumnC FROM TableC;
```

My workaround:

```
SELECT ColumnA FROM TableA;
/*SELECT ColumnB FROM TableB;
SELECT ColumnC FROM TableC;*/
```

Desired behaviour:

```
SELECT ColumnA FROM TableA;
DONTEXECUTEAFTERTHISLINE;
SELECT ColumnB FROM TableB;
SELECT ColumnC FROM TableC;
```

Comment: You may want to take a look at [`KILL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/kill.html).

Comment: Are you running this manually. Or is there some decision that can be made via code. Also if you are doing it manually what SQL editor are you running it from?

Comment: @JacquesRamsden some dude edited my question and removed the mysql-workbench tag. Yes, I'm running it manually.

Answer (score 0):

A partial solution: MySQL Workbench allows to select a number of lines and only execute those instead of the current command or the entire script.

Comment: Yes, but still a pain in the ass. I need something else.

Answer (score 0):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comments.html

Try Mysql Comment --

```
SELECT ColumnA FROM TableA;
-- DONTEXECUTEAFTERTHISLINE;
SELECT ColumnB FROM TableB;
SELECT ColumnC FROM TableC;
```

Comment: I want everything after the line 2 not to be executed.